# Kubuntu: show date and time on 2 lines

Tags: format, date

On one of my Kubuntu 14.04 systems, the date and time are displayed on separate lines.  On the other system, they're displayed on a single longer line. How can I control the number of lines?

Comment: In which context? Date/time is displayed in many places, by many different programs.

Comment: This is on the taskbar at the bottom of the screen.  Sorry -- I should have specified that.

Comment: More specifically, it's the Digital Clock widget.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post when you want to clarify something or add information? It’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's the panel height that makes the difference.  That can be controlled from Panel Options (right click on the K).